# Filter data.table on multiple criteria in the same column

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`:

```
> dt= data.table(num=c(1,2,1,1,2, 3, 3,2), letters[1:8])
> dt
   num V2
1:   1  a
2:   1  c
3:   1  d
4:   2  b
5:   2  e
6:   2  h
7:   3  f
8:   3  g
```

I want to filter all num equals to 1 and 2 and get the resulting data.table. I can do this with:

```
> dt[num==1 | num==2,]
   num V2
1:   1  a
2:   1  c
3:   1  d
4:   2  b
5:   2  e
6:   2  h
```

Or:

```
rbind(setkey(dt, num)[J(1)],setkey(dt, num)[J(2)])
```

But is there any option with setkey so that the second expression is shorter like:

```
setkey(dt, num)[1|2]
```

Since setkey code is quicker for very large amount ... I would appreciate some help!

Comment: Like this `setkey(dt, num)[num %in% c(1,2)]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In additions to KFB's comment:

```
setkey(dt, num)[num %in% c(1,2)]
```

If the filtering values are integers in a sequence:

```
setkey(dt,num)[J(1:2)]    # OR 
setkey(dt,num)[seq]
```

If they are arbitrary:

```
setkey(dt,num)[J(c(1,2)]
```

NOTE 1: This may not work in older versions of `data.table`
NOTE 2: `.` is a alias for `J` which is more readable:

```
 setkey(dt,num)[.(1:2)]
```

FWIW, I like using the `magrittr` package with `data.table` and making everything is clear as possible:

```
dt %>% setkey(num)
dt[ .(1:2) ]
```

The drawback is that you can't do this neatly on one line.